# Sitefinity 11 - add a step in checkout process

Tags: sitefinity

I am using Sitefinity 11, I want to add a new step in beginning & in between of it's Ecommerce checkout process. But I only get options to edit/modify the existing steps like **"Shipping/billing address form", "Shipping options", "Payment options", "Preview" & "Confirmation"** only.

[image]

Here, I want to add a step "**Company Information**" before "**Shipping/billing address form**" also I need to have separate steps for "**Shipping Information**" & "**Billing Information**".

I have tried to search a lot for any documentation/tutorial about such functionality, but found nothing.

I tried to create a form for "**Company Information**", I'll display this before checkout but I don't know how I cam map this form data to Order that will be created after checkout process.

If there's any existing functionality to achieve such scenario, that'll be great help.

Thanks

Comment: Also i would like to know whether i can have these steps as Accordion or i can only use the tab template for the checkout process? As far i have studied, i will have to create my custom checkout process if i have to use any other template other than tabbed template. Please help.

Comment: Found the solution to this problem ourself. Will post solution after few days.